# what happened when i press and hold button and close the application?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, notifications

im new in android programming . i want to know what whould happen when i closing the app by `holding button and sliding apps`

> onDestroy(); called ?

when i closing application in this way it seems that `AsyncTask` not closing completely .

i used a notification in my application and when im closing my app using `holding button and sliding apps` the notification wont disable .

this is my notification codes :

```
nman=(NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Long when=System.currentTimeMillis();
    final Notification n;
    n=new Notification(R.drawable.securitycameraicon,"security",when);
    Context context=getApplicationContext();
    String Title1="Warning";
    String Text1="this application working in background ";
    Intent notifintent=new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
    notifintent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    notifintent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    PendingIntent pending;
    pending=PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,notifintent,0);
    n.setLatestEventInfo(context, Title1, Text1, pending);
    n.flags = Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR |Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS  ;
```

Comment: If your application working in background, AsyncTask is running also. Notification will be stay forever if you explicitly won't tap on it.

Comment: @Geralt ok , but if i close the app by holding home button and close the app AsyncTask should be gone , right ? so why the notification still runing ?

Comment: Notification is not running, is notified once and will stay in notificaton bar if you explicitly wo't close it.

Comment: @Geralt i created an exit option in my app and i put  case R.id.menu_exit: nman.cancel(0);  android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid()); its work perfect . but i want to disable notify when the user closing app by holding button and sliding app .